# Fillable PDF Forms on iPad

Tags: ios, pdf, pdf-generation

I've a specific requirement around creating and annotating PDF using iOS and Android application. My application require to create a PDF file from user input (will use native UIViews to gather the user input) and then email this pdf to another user. Another user might add annotation (Text input) out side my application even possible doing it on a PC and they will send back the annotated file to sender (iPad/Android App). iPad App now has to open the pdf file with annotation text, update it and save/send again.

Can you guys guide me if this is possible and can be achieved using some 3rd party PDF libraries?

Thanks for your direction.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [ILPDFKit](https://github.com/iwelabs/ILPDFKit), open source, although it says it's experimental.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that no one has answered this...

I've done a search on google and came up with these two, the first is OpenSource

http://pdfhummus.com/ with links within to their github repo and a wiki on how to use it, but I'm not familiar with the project to know of it's success.  I've sent a message to the author in hopes that he will reply with some pointer, his wiki has documentation on how to use in Mac OSX but while there are xcode projects in his demo and instructions for building in iOS, I'm still at a loss...

the other option is:
http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/ios_pdf_library.html
which is an sdk solution that you can license... :-/

the latter seems easier to use as it's well documented complete with examples and guides on what's needed to build out your app.  That of course means you need to think about licensing their sdk.